# An alternative proof that Buchsbaum rings are generalized Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, translation, cohen-macaulay-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring. $R$ is said to be Buchsbaum if, for each ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ generated by a full system of parameters, the number $\lambda_R(R/\mathfrak{q})-e_{\mathfrak{q}}(R)$ is independent of the particular parameter ideal $\mathfrak{q}$, where $\lambda_R(R/\mathfrak{q})$ is the length of the $R$-module $R/\mathfrak{q}$ and $e_\mathfrak{q}(R)$ is the Hilbert-Samuel multiplicity of the ideal $\mathfrak{q}$. Further, $R$ is said to be generalized Cohen-Macaulay (or have the finite length cohomology (FLC) property) if the lower local cohomology modules $H^j_\mathfrak{m}(R)$ have $\lambda_R(H^j_\mathfrak{m}(R))<\infty$ for all $0 \le j < \dim R$.

In their paper *Verallgemeinerte Cohen-Macaulay-Moduln*, Math. Nachr. 85, (1978), 57--73, Cuong, Schenzel, and Trung show that if $R$ is Buchsbaum, then it is also generalized Cohen-Macaulay. Their proof is rather involved, as they show 8 different conditions are all equivalent to $R$ being generalized Cohen-Macaulay, and at least one condition is obviously true of Buchsbaum rings. Their paper is also in German, which makes it less accessible to me.

Does anyone know of an alternative route to the proof that if $R$ is Buchsbaum, it is generalized Cohen-Macaulay that does not factor through the machinery of the CST paper above? Or, if not, a place where the proof has been reproduced in English? Thank you!

Edit: I should also add that I am aware of Schenzel's derived criterion for being Buchsbaum, i.e. Theorem 2.3 in *Applications of Dualizing Complexes to Buchsbaum Rings*, Adv. Math 44, (1982), 61-77. However, it appears to me that the proof does rely on the machinery in the cited Cuong-Schenzel-Trung paper.